# How is the error calculated when you have a batch size > 1?

Tags: error

There is nowhere an answer to be found for this.

So, when i have a batch size of 1, the network calculates an error and then uses it to backpropagate and adjust weights. But what actually happens when you have batch sizes bigger then 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the gradients calculated using the error on each sample from the batch are accumulated, then averaged. The average of the accumulation of gradients is then what is used to update the weights.